# How to show $P(X \ge E(X) + b) \le \frac{V(X)}{b^2+V(X)}$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

Let $X$ have finite variance and $b>0$. I want to show $$P(X \ge E(X) + b) \le \frac{V(X)}{b^2+V(X)}$$The exercise gives a hint: first show that $$(b+t)^2P(X\ge E(X)+b)\le V(X)+t^2$$
for $t\ge 0$.

I've looked for inequalities on the probability of $X\ge E(X)$ and the like, but I have found none that seem to fit this problem. Chebyshev's inequality for instance relates to the absolute value.

Is there a tool I don't know to break this probability down? Or does anyone see a cleverer way?

Comment: Hint: Consider Markov inequality $(\mathbb P(|Y| > s) \le \frac{\mathbb E[Y^2]}{s^2}])$ for $Y=(X-\mathbb E[X]) + t$ and $s=b+t$ and see what happens. Absolute value is not a problem, since $\{ Y > s \} \subset \{ |Y| > s\}$

Comment: See analogous question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/853950

Comment: @DominikKutek thanks, that last bit was the missing piece!